# как в argparse() в python3 обработать значение аргумента содержащее "-"

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

Подскажите, как в argparse() в python3 обработать значение аргумента содержащее "-"?

Например есть функция

```
 def createParser():
    """Парсим аргументы запуска скрипта"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--server_name', default='', help="Имя сервера с префиксом")
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', default='', help="username")
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--token', default='', help="API ключ")
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--items', default='', help='параметры запуска')
    return parser
```

и необходимо в --items передать параметр c дефисом, сам вызов выглядит так

> python3.7 runner.py --username user --token [*******] --items command_line=pwd;ls -la

и получаю выхлоп

> python3.7 runner.py --username user --token [*******] --items command_line=pwd;ls -la
> usage: runner.py [-h] [-s SERVER_NAME] [-u USERNAME] [-t TOKEN]
> [-i ITEMS]
>
> runner.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -la'

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте значение в кавычки оборачивать: `command_line="pwd;ls -la"`

Comment: argparse тут ни при чём, это ваш шелл делит строку на аргументы по пробелам. Оберните в кавычки, чтоб не делил.